# How to add extra parameter in views link in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

## My views

```
<td colspan="3"><%= link_to 'Next', simulation, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %></td>
```

## Controller of this class

```
def show
@simulation = current_user.simulations.find(params[:id])
....
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.html
end
end
```

Now, I want to add an extra parameter in above `link_to`, (Let's the parameter is `sc` with some value) So that I can access that variable in `controller` class in following way:

```
def show
 if (params[:sc])
   ....
 end
 @simulation = current_user.simulations.find(params[:id])
 ....
 respond_to do |format|
   format.js
   format.html
  end
 end
```

How can I do that? I am new to `rails`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
view:
<%= link_to 'Next', simulation_path(sc: value) %>

controller:
if params[:sc] && params[:sc] == ?
  etc.
```

It's as simple as that. :)